# Detecção de Outliers com python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, ciência-de-dados

Olá. Estou atualmente aprendendo Data Science, atualmente estou no inicio de Machine Learning, e durante meus estudos percebi vi que os dados tem de estar organizados e dentro de "linha, "dados muito extravagantes podem causar problemas no modelo".

Então, estou em um projeto para tentar prever o proximo valor do fechamento e abertura da ação PETR4.SA(ação da Petrobras), porém não consegui plotar o gráfico para o calculo de outlier. Como faço isso?

[image: Imagem do DataFrame]

E essas são as bibliotecas que estou usando:

```
#Analise exploratoria de dados

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Visualização
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

#Drive
from google.colab import files
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dá para usar estratégias de filtros para evitar picos e pontos fora da curva, em vários domínios de dados (isso é - dados de várias áreas do saber: em saúde um valor fora poderia identificar uma medida de exame copiada errada, ou tomada num momento de stress, por exemplo). Mas s está usando para cotações de ativos - acredito que faz sentido usar os valores como estão - tirar os "outliers" iria acabar com qualquer utilidade do seu modelo -
Se o valor de fechamento no dia 2/12 foi 3% maior, ele foi 3% maior - não é uma configuração errada em uma foto, um ruído elétrico num instrumento analógico, etc... você tem que levar essa variação em conta.

Mais ainda, pode ser que justamente por conta dessa característica dos dados de mercado - (eles já são imputados a partir de sistemas digitais), você simplesmente não tenha *nenhum* ponto que seria um "outlier" nos dados em que está trabalhando - pode até ser que você tenha feito tudo certo.

Como você não colocou uma forma de a gente poder te ajudar de forma mais concreta: nem o código que está usando para plotar os dados, nem uma forma de quem estiver respondendo ter o dataframe para criar algumas plotagens de exemplo, não é possível ajudar você além desse ponto.

É fácil encontrar artigos sobre o tema, mas suponho que você já tenha passado por alguns. Esse aqui parece razoavelmente fácil de seguir e completo:
https://towardsdatascience.com/ways-to-detect-and-remove-the-outliers-404d16608dba